# Parallel processing large SQL table with Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, informix

I am trying to process about 7 million rows daily from an Informix table with Apache Camel but I can't figure out how it can be accomplished.

My first attempt that was working with a very low set of data (about 50k rows) was using `.split(body()).parallelProcessing()` like so:

```
from("quartz2://transaccionesGroup/myTimerTransaction?cron=0+1+0+*+*+?")
.bean(QueryTable.class, "queryData").split(body()).parallelProcessing() // Essentially executes a query on my table and returns a list of MyTable.class
.bean(ProcessTable.class, "processData") // Converts each MyTable object into another type of object (NewData.class) for later processing, storing in them in a synchronized list
.end().to("direct:transform-data");

from("direct:transform-data")
.bean(ProcessNewData.class, "processNewData").split(body()).parallelProcessing() // Obtains list
.bean(AnalyzeData.class, "analyze") // Analyzes the data
.bean(PersistData.class, "persist") // Persists the new data on other tables
.end();
```

This of course resulted in an "OutOfMemory" error when I tried it with 500k rows on `.bean(QueryTable.class, "queryData").split(body()).parallelProcessing()` because it first tried caching all of the data from the query before parsing it. I tried setting `fetchSize` to something like 100 but I got the same error, and using `maxRows` would only get me the amount of rows I specified and ignore the rest.

My next attempt was using one of Camel's components like [sql-component](http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html) and [jdbc](http://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html) and trying to use a Splitter to process each row in separate threads but I got the same exact problem.

sql:

```
from("quartz2://transaccionesGroup/myTimerTransaction?cron=0+1+0+*+*+?")
.bean(QueryTable.class, "queryDataParams") // Gets the params for my query
.to("sql:SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date_received BETWEEN :#startDate AND :#endDate?dataSource=dataSourceInformix").split(body()).parallelProcessing()
// The rest would be essentially the same
```

jdbc:

```
from("quartz2://transaccionesGroup/myTimerTransaction?cron=0+1+0+*+*+?")
.bean(QueryTable.class, "queryString") // Gets the query to execute
.to("jdbc:dataSourceInformix").split(body()).parallelProcessing()
```

My last attempt was to use `maxMessagesPerPoll` for sql and `outputType=StreamList` for jdbc components but unfortunatelly the former only processes one row at a time (as well as it has to be a consumer to be used as such) and the latter gives me an `java.sql.SQLException: Cursor not open` exception.

sql:

```
from("sql:" + query +"?dataSource=dataSourceInformix&maxMessagesPerPoll=100") // I need to be able to use the quartz2 component
```

jdbc:

```
.to("jdbc:dataSourceInformix?outputType=StreamList").split(body()).streaming() // Throws exception
```

The end goal is to be able to process millions of rows without consuming so much memory so as to prevent the "OutOfMemory" error. My idea, if possible is to do the following:

1. Create my query on quartz cron-trigger
2. Obtain and group N amount of results
3. Send a group of results to be process (in another thread) whilst another group is being obtained
4. Repeat untill all data has been processed

I know this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764814/camel-sql-consumer-performance-for-large-datasets) but the answer doesn't really help my situation. I also noticed that in the documentation for the sql component it has an `outputType=StreamList` option for the producer but it is implemented on version 2.18 and higher while I have version 2.14.1.

Any help and tips would be extremely helpful!

Thanks.

Some other info:
Apache Camel Version: 2.14.1
Database: Informix

Comment: From the docs (http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html) it looks like the StreamList facility might be the only way to do this Camel-native. Alternatively, you can create a class which manually makes the SQL query, acquires a cursor (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)) and then hands off batches of, say, 10k rows at a time to another route for processing. You can use a seda queue (http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) and provision a max size and have your custom class sleep until there's availability, so you don't choke the downstream.

Comment: @NotaJD Thanks for the advice on the seda queue, I will look into it. As for the cursor, I tried using `JdbcTemplate.fetchSize=100` in the QueryTable class, but for some reason the option was ignored. I also tried limiting the results via query and, although it worked for the first 2 iterations, the subsequent iterations slowed down the process and errored out.

Comment: is autocommit off for your JdbcTemplate? I recall some drivers have issues with autocommit and streaming results. Also how are you validating fetchSize is ignored? This param attempts to fix the number of rows returned when you have a cursor open (e.g. if your query returns 10 million rows, it'll fetch 100 at a time from the DB on the wire, that's theory anyway).

Comment: @NotaJD When using the `resetAutoCommit=false` of the jdbc endpoint options it doesn't give me an error. As for the validation of fetchSize, I set a very low size and tried working with that, but it never passed the execution and threw the error. I tried using a RowCallbackHandler and that seems to work, but unfortunatelly it gives me an `GC overhead limit exceeded` exception at around 280k records in my list.

Comment: Can you set up a standalone/isolated test using "raw" JdbcTemplate, that executes the query and successful reads each row from the recordset (i.e. just call while (rs.hasNext()) { rs.next(); }). If it's streaming and cursoring (etc) it should not run out of memory.

Comment: @NotaJD That's pretty much how I was doing it: String query; jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(); jdbc.setFetchSize(100); rs = jdbc.queryForRowSet(query); while(rs.next()){...}; Logger.INFO("Done!"). This however still threw the exception before entering the loop.

Comment: What DataSource are you using with your JdbcTemplate? If it's a pool, are you 100% sure you're telling the pool to set auto commit to false? E.g. for DBCP2 (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) it's defaultAutoCommit

Comment: Do you have some queue-based technology available, to allow you to read the records and write them to a queue, and have Camel pick them up from there? 
If not, Camel's SQL component can be used as a consumer, to poll a table... do you have control to add columns to this table?

Comment: @NotaJD Sorry, I was assgined to another project and just got back to this. As for the DataSource I stated it was Informix and for the pool I stated in my answer that I set the autoCommit to false in order for streamming to work.

Comment: @DariusX. I am only allowed to read from the table, so I cannot add any columns or records. Also, I don't have any queueing system available and would rather not have to implement one for this would only be run once a week after some time.

Comment: DataSource->https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html

Comment: If a queueing system isn't already available, Camel's SEDA could substitute. From your answer, it sounds like you're doing that.

Answer (score 6):

After quite a bit of research, some more trial and error and the [tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407892/parallel-processing-large-sql-table-with-camel?noredirect=1#comment97557591_55407892) from NotaJD, I found a solution that could work out (still testing). Actually make that 2 solutions, but they differ in just their type of execution.

### Info:

For the sakes of explanation I will use the following info:

- Table has 7 million records (rows)
- `AggregationStrategyImpl` extends `AggregationStrategy` with the following:

  - Returns a `List<Object>` in the exchange body
  - The aggregation `Predicate` completes when `List<Object> >= 50000`
  - The aggregation timeout is set to `30000` milliseconds
- `CustomThreadPool` is a pseudo-implementation of Camel's `ThreadPoolBuilder` class:

  - PoolSize: 100
  - MaxPoolSize: 50000
  - MaxQueueSize: 500
  - TimeUnit: MILLISECONDS
  - KeepAliveTime: 30000
- Both implementations are being autowired

### Solution 1:

```
from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerTransaction?cron=0+1+0+*+*+?")
.bean(QueryTable.class, "createQuery")
```

The code will still run on Quartz cron-timer (00:01 every day) but this time my `QueryTable.class` will fetch the proper query to execute (instead of `SELECT *`, I now specified the columns I need) and set it to the exchange body.

```
.to("jdbc:dataSourceInformix?resetAutoCommit=false&outputType=StreamList").split(body()).streaming()
.bean(TransformRecord.class, "process")
```

The Camel `jdbc` component will take the query from the exchange body, set the `resetAutoCommit` to false so it doesn't throw the `Cursor not open` error, set the output to streamming and split-stream the execution, thus I will not query all records at once but instead one by one. Every record fetched will then be tranformed into a proper POJO via `TransformRecord.class`.

```
.aggregate(constant(true), aggregationStrategyImpl)
.completionPredicate(aggregationStrategyImpl.getCompletionPredicate())
.completionTimeout(aggregationStrategyImpl.getCompletionTimeout())
.to("direct:start-processing")
.end();
```

This time I use an `aggregate` component to create a list of records. The `aggregationStrategyImpl` contains the logic for aggregation as well as the completion predicate and timeout, thus when I reach a certain amount of records (or a timeout occurs) the list will be sent to "direct:start-processing".

More on the aggregation implementation in this Source Allies [blog](https://www.sourceallies.com/2014/01/how-to-implement-the-splitter-and-aggregator-patterns-with-apache-camel/) and in the Apache Camel [Aggregate EIP](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/74d1b9b6e709ae11409b69bb200ee350e949c0d2/core/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/aggregate-eip.adoc) docs.

```
from("direct:start-processing")
.split(body()).executorService(customThreadPool.build(getContext()))
.bean(AnalyzeData.class, "analyze")
.bean(PersistData.class, "persist")
.end();
```

Here I split the list obtained and using a custom ThreadPool I create N amount of threads to analyze and process each record individually. This way I can process my list in parallel processing instead of one by one. I could have used `.split(body()).parallelProcessing()` but the default ThreadPool settings might not be optimal later on.

More on the ThreadPool implementation on the Apache Camel [Threading Model](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/67b3fa5781dec77cb6d908730ef916782785214d/docs/user-manual/modules/ROOT/pages/threading-model.adoc) docs, the [ThreadPool Configuration](http://camel.apache.org/camel-23-threadpool-configuration.html) notes and the Red Hat [Threading Model](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/html/apache_camel_development_guide/basicprinciples-thread) docs.

### Solution 2:

For this solution it is basically the extact same execution but with the following changes:

```
// .to("direct:start-processing")
.to("seda:start-processing?size=1&blockWhenFull=true")
.end();
// from("direct:start-processing")
from("seda:start-processing?size=1&blockWhenFull=true")
// continues normally
```

What this would do is send the list to be processes **asynchronously**, allowing up to 1 other list to be queued in-memory and pausing the parent thread if the queue is full. So instead of waiting for the list of records to be processed the parent thread would go back and collect another batch of records. This also means that in case the processing route hasn't finished, the new records won't get thrown out and the parent thread would wait until it can send the batch to the SEDA in-memory queue.

More on the SEDA component on the Apache Camel SEDA Component docs in [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-seda/src/main/docs/seda-component.adoc) and in their [site](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/seda.html)

### Conclusions:

With solution 1 it should take much longer to complete since it is processing all the data first before gathering more records from the query, but the memory consuption should be FAR less since it is controlled in the aggregation predicate.

With solution 2 it should be much faster since it is gathering the next batch of records from the query while processing the previous batch, but the memory consumption would be FAR greater since it would hold at most 3 lists: the one being processed, the one in the SEDA queue and the latest batch gathered by the parent thread (paused when queue is full).

I stated that I am still testing these solutions because with the 500k records it works, but I'm still working out the optimal ThreadPool settings for the server where this will be implemented in. I have researched about threading in Java but it seems that there really isn't that much to go by other than the system's architecture, RAM and trial and error.

Comment: Were you able to achieve parallelism with this approach? Also, does streamList in camel jdbc work as expected?

Comment: @KaifKhan I did. I actually used the JDBC StreamList functionality, the AggregationStrategy and the seda endpoint using a  "size=5&blockWhenFull=true" to achieve this.

Comment: I also tried JDBC streamList, but it seems it loads all the data in memory first and then streams it. Did you observe this behaviour of streamList or it worked as expected for millions of records?

Comment: @KaifKhan It did work as expected. It was a combination of using solution 1 with solution 2.